# using trapezoidal numerical integration in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I need to integrate this function using trapezoidal rule in python:

theta = .518/r^2 * dr/(sqrt(2*1.158 + 2/r - .518^2/2r^2))

I have written my code and I should be seeing an ellipsoidal structure when plotted. theta should run from 0 to 2pi and r_min = .16 & r_max = .702

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b-a)/n
    result = 0.5*f(a) + 0.5*f(b)
    for i in range(1, n):
        result += f(a + i*h)
    result *= h
    return result


intg =[]
v = lambda r: (0.5108/(r**2))* (1./np.sqrt(2*1.158+(2/r)-.5108**2/(2*r**2)))
n = np.arange(1,1000,100)
theta = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,100)
for j in n:

    numerical = trapezoidal(v, .16,.702 , j)
    intg.append(numerical)




plt.plot(numerical,theta)
plt.show()
```

I am doing some very elementary mistake I guess, because I am getting no plot out of it. I think the trapezoidal routine is correct, because it worked for other functions. your help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine).

```
import numpy as np
import quadpy


val = quadpy.line_segment.integrate_split(
    lambda r: 0.5108/r**2 / np.sqrt(2*1.158 + 2/r - 0.5108**2/(2*r**2)),
    0.15, 0.702, 100,
    quadpy.line_segment.Trapezoidal()
    )
print(val)
```

gives `0.96194633532`. The trapezoidal formula is mostly implemented for historical purposes, however. A better and equally simple rule is `quadpy.line_segment.Midpoint`. An even better approach is certainly adaptive quadrature

```
val, error_estimate = quadpy.line_segment.integrate_adaptive(
        lambda r: 0.5108/r**2 / np.sqrt(2*1.158 + 2/r - 0.5108**2/(2*r**2)),
        [0.15, 0.702],
        1.0e-10
        )
print(val)
```

which gives the more accurate `0.961715309492`, or even tanh-sinh quadrature

```
val, error_estimate = quadpy.line_segment.tanh_sinh(
        lambda r: 0.5108/r**2 / np.sqrt(2*1.158 + 2/r - 0.5108**2/(2*r**2)),
        0.15, 0.702,
        1.0e-30
        )
print(val)
```

which gives `0.9617153094932353183036398697528`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.

First one is that the third argument in `np.arrange` is not the number of values to be generated but the step. This means that `theta` will have only one value and that `n` and thus `intg` will have 10 instead of 100 values.

Assuming that was your intention (100 values) you can do this

```
intg =[]
v = lambda r: (0.5108/(r**2))* (1./np.sqrt(2*1.158+(2/r)-.5108**2/(2*r**2)))
n = np.arange(1,1000,10)
theta = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/100)
#print theta
for j in n:
    numerical = trapezoidal(v, .16,.702 , j)
    intg.append(numerical)
```

Then you're plotting `numerical` which is basically a single number and what you probably wanted to plot was the integral value `intg` - to do so you also need to convert `intg` from a list into `np.array`:

```
intg = np.array(intg)
```

With these changes the program works as intended,

```
plt.plot(intg,theta)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the lengths of your numerical and theta, you will see that they are empty lists/arrays.

Try the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = float(b-a)/n
    result = 0.5*f(a) + 0.5*f(b)
    for i in range(1, n):
        result += f(a + i*h)
    result *= h
    return result


intg =[]
v = lambda r: (0.5108/(r**2))* (1./np.sqrt(2*1.158+(2/r)-.5108**2 /(2*r**2)))
n = np.arange(1, 1001)
theta = np.linspace(0,2.*np.pi,1000)

for j in n:
    numerical = trapezoidal(v, .16,.702 , j)
    intg.append(numerical)


plt.plot(intg,theta)
plt.show()
```